# Matplotlib - uneven intervals between x-axis with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am currently experiencing an issue where the spaces between ticks on my plot appear to have uneven intervals when using a `DatetimeIndex` for my x-axis. The code is as follows:

```
x = pd.date_range('2018-11-03', '2018-12-30')
plt.plot(x, np.arange(len(x)))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Note the two instances in which the dates do not increment by the typical 7-day period. Even after extending the time period, the issue persists:

```
x = pd.date_range('2018-11-03', '2019-03-20')
plt.plot(x, np.arange(len(x)))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

How can I override this behavior to have standard 7-day intervals on my plot? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use matplotlib's ticker module to customize tick locations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = pd.date_range('2018-11-03', '2019-03-20')
plt.plot(x, np.arange(len(x)))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(7))
```

The above script returns the following image:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks. Does the job. I'm curious as to why this behavior is occurring in the first place? I recall `matplotlib` adjusting for the optimal spaces automatically.

Comment: I am also surprised that you got uneven tick labels in the first place. Running your script under Python 3.5.4 (Spyder IDE 2.3.8) yielded a figure with evenly spaced tick labels (14-days interval).

Comment: Currently using anaconda so I'll try a fresh install. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: This behaviour should be improved in Matplotlib 3.1 (~Feb).  The ticks will fall on the first or fifteenth.

Note that AutoDateLocator has a kwarg: `interval_multiples=True` that used to default to False.  Hence ticks fell every 14 days, no matter where in the month they were (1 Jan, 15 jan, 29 Jan, 12 Feb).  That was changed, but you can still set to False if you prefer to get the old behaviour back.