# Why do I get uneven intervals between tick locations with datetime in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new here so I can't comment on another post.  This is really a follow-up to @GardenQuant's question here:  [Matplotlib - uneven intervals between x-axis with datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057567/matplotlib-uneven-intervals-between-x-axis-with-datetime) .

I'm seeing similar output from a date (or datetime:  I tried it both ways to see if it made a difference) list of the first 20 Fridays in 2017:  tick locations of 1st and 22nd of each month.  I updated matplotlib from 3.3.4 to 3.5.1 (Jupyter Notebook is my IDE) and I still get the same thing.  I've seen others describe getting tick locations of the 1st and 15th of each month.  This would make more sense to me as being more evenly-spaced in contrast to 1st and 22nd, which is lopsided.

```
from datetime import date #what if we use date module rather than datetime?
from datetime import timedelta
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fri_2017 = [] #2017_Fri gives "invalid decimal literal" at the underscore
random_pnl_list = []
cumul_pnl_from_random = []

start_date = date(2017,1,1) #no datetime(yyyy,mm,dd)
while True: #True must be capitalized
    if start_date.weekday() == 4:
        Fri_2017.append(start_date)
        break
    else:
        start_date += timedelta(days=1)
for i in range(19):
    Fri_2017.append(Fri_2017[-1] + timedelta(days=7))

converted_Fri_2017 = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in Fri_2017] #list comprehension
#print(converted_Fri_2017)

for i in range(20):
    random_pnl_list.append(random.randint(-1000,1000))

cumul_pnl_from_random = list(np.cumsum(random_pnl_list)) #np returns array but this MUCH easier than doing loop to compute
#print(random_pnl_list)
#print(cumul_pnl_from_random)

fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2)

plt.sca(ax1) #sca = "set current axis." By default, "last" axes (lower/ax2) are current.  This changes current to ax1.
plt.plot(Fri_2017,cumul_pnl_from_random)
plt.xticks(rotation=90) #more accurate to say this operates on the _current_ axes (upper).
plt.sca(ax2)
plt.plot(converted_Fri_2017,cumul_pnl_from_random)
plt.xticks(rotation=90) #as current axes are now ax2 (L36), this operates on lower axes.

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show() #this gives same result after updating mpl to 3.5.1 from 3.3.4
```

My solution is this, which then evenly plots every weekly label:

```
converted_Fri_2017 = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in Fri_2017]
```

I'm still wondering why it happens in the first place, though.  I would prefer to let mpl automatically scale the axis and plot consistent intervals.  This is anything but.

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [reprex] including sample data.

Comment: Done.  I wasn't sure how to include multiple lines as code in the post.